# Flexbox column with Angular 2

Tags: css, angular

I'm trying to make a UI layout with 100% height using flexbox. The problem is, this is an Angular 2 app so elements are added in that I don't really have any control of.

[Here's my demo](http://codepen.io/harangue/pen/ZQJROe?editors=110). As you can see, inside each `.tab` div (which you can think of like a page) there is another div that is hidden programatically. When this inner div is hidden, I would like the parent div to be effectively hidden as well, allowing the visible `.tab` to take up the entire remaining height.

```html
<div class="foo">
  <header>A</header>
  <main>B</main>
  <nav>
    <div class="tab">
      <div style="display: none;">Foo</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab">
      <div>Bar (I want this at the top)</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab">
      <div style="display: none;">Baz</div>
    </div>
    <ul>
      <li>Foo</li>
      <li>Bar</li>
      <li>Baz</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

My HTML isn't really flexible because of the way Angular 2 components work. How can I achieve my desired behavior?

Comment: The easy way:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/ElementRef-class.html

The right way I belive you have to send an event to the parent and have the parent hide the whole directive instead of you hiding only the content of the directive from whithin the component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use directives as:

```
*ngIf, *ngClass, *ngStyle
```

To control style and visibility in DOM.

```
<div *ngIf="isActive === first" class="tab">
  <div style="display: none;">Foo</div>
</div>
<div *ngIf="isActive === second" class="tab">
  <div>Bar (I want this at the top)</div>
</div>
<div *ngIf="isActive === third" class="tab">
  <div style="display: none;">Baz</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yep this is essentially how I ended up rewriting it. Not super satisfied, but until `display: contents;` has achieved widespread adoption, this is probably the best I can do.